# Таблицы в xib для iPad

Tags: ipad, xib, ios

Не могу понять как создать в xib интерфейсе таблицу с несколькими колонками определенной длины и строками для iPad.
Где то пишут, что должна существовать настройка colums но её нет.
Кто то пишет, что нужно добавить табличное представление, аоптом в него представление ячейки, но оно не вставляется в табличное.

Подскажите по действиям, именно в интерфесе, как создать таблицу с определенными строками и столбцами.

Answer (score 1):

У класса UITableView колонка всего одна. Ты с OS X не перепутал?
Тебе нужно или сделать свой класс для ячеек (чтоб ячейка представляла собой строку таблицы) или использовать UICollectionView.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/